# osx - Mac - Python 3.5 - ImportError: No module named 'cubicspline' when testing python package

Tags: python, macos, ipython, python-3.5, python-import

I recently downloaded a package and when testing the package to see if everything works correctly I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'cubicspline'`. When following the trail to see where is error occurs I found that `cubicspline.py` (the file not being found) is in the same folder as `extcurve_s16.py` (the file calling cubicspline).

```
    File "/Users/Austin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/isochrones/schlafly/extcurve_s16.py", line 4, in <module>
import cubicspline
```

I've checked the permissions on the folder and I'm able to both read and write. There is also an `__init__.py` file in the folder. Any ideas here? I can't figure out why it wouldn't be able to call a file that is in the same folder. Here is the exact chunk of code for reference, as can be seen `import numpy` works fine.

```
    import numpy
    import cubicspline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by cloning the `isochrones` package from Github instead of using `pip install isochrones`. There was some type of issue with the `pip` version.